# is fantom generated bytecode as performant as java equivalent bytecode?

Tags: java, performance, bytecode, fantom

from the many jvm languages appearing nowdays, there's one that seems to be particularly appealing

have a look at

http://fantom.org/doc/docIntro/Tour.html

I just wonder if, when ignoring the dynamic typing feature, the generated bytecode is performant equivalent to java...

ps: added aclaration about performance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did some quicksort performance testing.

```
Int[100.000] array quicksort
  Java ~ 11ms
  Java using long and ArrayList<Long> ~ 66ms
  Fantom ~ 97 ms

Int[1.000.000] array quicksort
  Java ~ 91ms
  Java using long and ArrayList<long> ~ 815ms
  Fantom ~ 1100ms.
```

<del>So I'd say that at the moment Fantom's code runs about 10x slower than Java's code. However do note that I used Java's int and Fantom's Int which aren't the same. Java's int are 32-bit and Fantom's are 64-bit</del>.

After profiling things a bit there are indications that Fantom code is almost performant as 
Java. However if performance is **absolutely** critical, stay away from Lists, use platform specific versions of [lists](http://fantom.org/doc/docLang/JavaFFI.html#arrays) or drop down to native and write in Java.

EDIT: I had a talk with brian and he confirmed my suspicions. The reason Fantom is slower is because all it's `Int` are 64-bit integer and all `Int[]` arrays are similar to `ArrayList<Long>`. The new test show the difference. The reason Fantom is still slower is probably that its Duration, Int and List classes have a lot more methods/fields than plain `ArrayList` or `Integer` or `System.currentMillis`. It's a tradeoff that may or may not suit you. If you really need high performance just make a native method and program it in Java/C#/Javascript. That way you'll get Java equivalent performance.

Here are sources if you want to test it yourself:

Fantom source:

```
class TestQuickSort
{

   public static Void swap(Int[] a, Int i, Int j) {  
    temp := a[i];  
    a[i] = a[j];  
    a[j] = temp;  
   }  

   public static Void quicksortA(Int[] a, Int L, Int R) {  
    m := a[(L + R) / 2];  
    i := L;  
    j := R;  
    while (i <= j) {  
     while (a[i] < m)  
      i++;  
     while (a[j] > m)  
      j--;  
     if (i <= j) {  
      swap(a, i, j);  
      i++;  
      j--;  
     }  
    }  
    if (L < j)  
     quicksortA(a, L, j);  
    if (R > i)  
     quicksortA(a, i, R);  
   }  

   public static Void quicksort(Int[] a) {  
    quicksortA(a, 0, a.size - 1);  
   }   

  static Void main(Str[] args) {  

    // Sample data  
    a := Int[,]

    for(i := 0; i<1000000; i++)
    {
      a.add(i*3/2+1)
      if(i%3==0) {a[i]=-a[i]}
    }

    t1 := Duration.now 
    quicksort(a);  
    t2 := Duration.now 
    echo((t2-t1).toMillis)  

   }  
}
```

And java with all the Ints replaced by longs and ArrayList. Original Java implementation can be found at http://stronglytypedblog.blogspot.com/2009/07/java-vs-scala-vs-groovy-performance.html.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class QuicksortJava {  

 public static void swap(ArrayList<Long> a, long i, long j) {  
  long temp = a.get((int)i);  
  a.set((int)i, a.get((int)j));  
  a.set((int)j, temp);  
 }  

 public static void quicksort(ArrayList<Long> a, long L, long R) {  
  long m = a.get((int)(L + R) / 2);  
  long i =  L;  
  long j =  R;  
  while (i <= j) {  
   while (a.get((int)i) < m)  
    i++;  
   while (a.get((int)j) > m)  
    j--;  
   if (i <= j) {  
    swap(a, i, j);  
    i++;  
    j--;  
   }  
  }  
  if (L < j)  
   quicksort(a, L, j);  
  if (R > i)  
   quicksort(a, i, R);  
 }  

 public static void quicksort(ArrayList<Long> a) {  
  quicksort(a, 0, a.size() - 1);  
 }  

 public static void main(String[] args) {  

  // Sample data  
  long size = 100000;
  ArrayList<Long> a = new ArrayList<Long>((int)size);  
  for (long i = 0; i < size; i++) {  
   a.add(i * 3 / 2 + 1);  
   if (i % 3 == 0)  
    a.set((int)i, -a.get((int)i));  
  }  

  long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();  
  quicksort(a);  
  long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();  
  System.out.println(t2 - t1);  

 }  

}
```

Comment: I'd say ultimate answer would be **Profile it**. Fantom can output `.jar` files and you can use any Java profiler to examine it. Then you could try to optimize performance critical segments with `native`. Most of the time it has same performance as Java using ArrayList and Long (for arrays and integers respectively).

Comment: "So I'd say that at the moment Fantom's bytecode runs about 10x slower than Java's bytecode." This is just incorrect. You draw much to far-reaching conclusions from a single micro benchmark, even considering the Int <-> Double effect. A reasonable conclusion would be: There is a vague hint that Fantom is almost as fast as Java, but beware of List of Int becase they are slow.

Comment: True, but that was written before I made my remark below. Anyway the thing has been fixed. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

I have **no** experience with fantom, but it looks like the fantom interpreter *can use* java, .net or JS libraries, but it's not that the fantom *compiled bytecode* can be read out of the box by java, .net or javascript.

Having said that... I'll check it later, it looks interesting :)

Comment: Yes, that is true; However you can simply force Fantom to output `.jar` file instead of a `.pod` (Fantom's `.jar` analogue). Also iirc Fantom has Java FFI but not .Net and JS (it's still in development).

Answer (score 2):

Fantom compiles down to its own byte-code format called "fcode" - which is then translated to java byte code or IL at runtime - see this page for more details:

http://fantom.org/doc/docLang/Deployment.html

JavaScript works a bit different - actual JavaScript source code is produced at compile time from the Fantom source code (along with all the meta-data the Fantom runtime needs) - to produce a standalone js file you can run directly in your browser.